# CSRF - Instagram Account Login

Tags: c#, authentication, https, request, csrf-token

#### Introduction

**Hi**, I'm currently trying to develop a console application that sends requests to the instagram server for login.

#### Problem

I currently do not know how to modify the source code to use the **CSRF** token to log in with an Instagram account.

#### Note

> I would like to receive directly
> the modified source code directly, that would help me 100 times better
> than to send me a documentation page.

#### Source Code

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    Console.Write("Username: ");

    string username = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Password: ");

    string password = Console.ReadLine();

    string postData = "username" + username + "&password=" + password + "&response_type=token";

    var postResult = await client.PostAsync("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/", new StringContent(postData, new UTF8Encoding()));

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine(postResult);
    Console.WriteLine("");
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Hello, would it be possible to answer my question now? Or should I edit it further?

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Are you asking how to get the token, it seems you don't have that?

Comment: No, I want to use the token to log in to an Instagram account, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: See new question. The new question is far better now.

Comment: Sorry it's late getting back to you. I am not sure myself about this, I use the API they provide to do this and works just fine. I found a solution that I used awhile ago that didn't use an API. Unfortunately the only thing that is still working is getting the CRSF token, but not allowing me to login using that token; I keep getting a 400 error when attempting it. I'm not sure if they patched this or not, I'm only receiving that error which doesn't provide much details.

Comment: On another note, typically you would follow the oauth route to get a token that then is used to make request calls to the service if need to be. That requires I believe a client id and client  code/secret that's generated in the developer portal.